# Xamarin forms interaction with aot and mono

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/understanding-the-xamarin-mobile-platform) that `Xamarin.ios` uses aot and `Xamarin.android` uses mono.

I want to know whether this also applies to the `Xamarin.forms` or only to `Xamarin.ios` and `Xamarin.android`?

If the second latter is true then how are `Xamarin.forms` handled?

Comment: XF apps include a "head" project for each platform.  So if you build your Forms project for iOS, it uses AOT.

Comment: so if I have XF and have iOS and Android.. each will then compile differently. For iOs it will use AOT and for Android it will use Mono not AOT. The Xamarin forms just enables the view sharing but the compile time is different? Is that correct?

Comment: When does iOS get translated to IL?

Comment: Both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android use Mono. See also ["What is Xamarin?"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin).   ["Xamarin.iOS applications are fully Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiled from C# into native ARM assembly code."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin#xamarinios)

Comment: @Benl thank you, I will have look

Answer (score 0):

Mono is used in all Xamarin Platforms, AOT in Xamarin.iOS is always compulsory because that is Apple's requirement. For Android you can optionally have AOT enable in Xamarin.Android with the cost of slower build time, however it improves the Start up time of the app.
More info: [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-android-aot-works/)